# Save multiple images in database

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, image

I have 3 images that changes on click , and I want to save what ever the user choose from the images to the database so it will be uploaded in another page , I'm not sure if it's possible that's why I'm asking .

```
<form name="massage-box" id="inp" class="con" action="http://localhost/Folder/massage.php" method="POST" >
            <textarea name="textmassage" id="massage"  type="text"  class="inputs inputtotextfeild" placeholder="Write your massage here ." required></textarea>
            <img class="icn1" src="pic1.png" id="geticon" onclick="iconfun()" >
            <img class="icn2" src="pic11.png" id="geticon2" onclick="iconfun2()">
            <img class="icn3" src="pic111.png" id="geticon3" onclick="iconfun3()">
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="sbmtcom">Post massage </button>
        </form>
```

I'll provide one of the three images java script code because all of them has the same coding way

```
var counter = 0,
    gallery = ["pic1.png", "pic2.png", "pic3.png", "pic4.png", "pic5.png", "pic6.png"],
   iconfun = function () {
        document.getElementById("geticon").src = gallery[counter];
        counter++;
        if (counter >= gall

ery.length) {
            counter = 0;
}
```

and here is the PHP code :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{    
     $textmassage = $_POST['textmassage'];
     $geticon = $_POST['geticon'];
     $geticon2 = $_POST['geticon2'];
    $geticon3 = $_POST['geticon3'];
    
     $sql = "INSERT INTO massageform (textmassage,geticon,geticon2,geticon3)
     VALUES ('$textmassage','$geticon',' $geticon2',' $geticon3')";
}
```

Comment: _"I'm not sure if it's possible"_ - in software, almost anything is possible. You're saving the data to a database. What's stopping you from running a `SELECT` query in a different page to retrieve it?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular running SELECT query in a different page ? how ? can you give me an example to understand if it's ok with you ?

Comment: Note that a message and a massage are two distinctly different things.

Comment: @Strawberry just a typo thing

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to save them temporarily would you consider putting them into the session?

```
$_SESSION['geticon3'] = $_POST['geticon3'];
```

Comment: it says " Undefined array key "geticon"  "

Comment: @nothere there's no geticon here